# Problems in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

There is this rather hard linear algebra problem in my notes that the professor left as an exercise during the holidays if we have free time, and it goes:

> **Problem:** Let $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the vector space of all $n \times n$ matrices over the real number line. For $A \in$ $M_n(\mathbb{R}),$ let $A^t$ denote the transpose of matrix $A$. Define the linear operators $\tau_A: M_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow  M_n(\mathbb{R})$ by $\tau_A(X) = AXA^t$. Prove that $\text{Tr}(\tau_A)$ is $\text{Tr}(A)^2$ and $\text{Det}(\tau_A)$ is $\text{Det}(A)^{2n}.$

Can anyone give me some start so I can get going with this problem? I would appreciate the help.

Comment: For starters, try tackling the special case where $A$ is diagonal.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but could you give me some more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic approaches to this problem.  One is to find the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the transformation, and then to compute the trace/determinant using the product/sum (I think this is what Qiaochu has in mind).  The other is to try to interpret the trace/determinant in the context of maps on $M_n(\Bbb R)$.

**Hint:** (For approach 1) Suppose that $A$ is diagonal.  What do the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $A$ look like?  Consider in particular the case where all eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct.  Now, what do the eigenvectors of $A$ look like if $A$ is *diagonalizable*?

Once you have the result for diagonalizable matrices, you can get the general result either using the continuity of trace/determinant, or by extending our argument above using Jordan form.

**Hint:** (For approach 2) We may compute the trace of a map $\tau:M_n(\Bbb R)\to M_n(\Bbb R)$ as
$$
\sum_{i,j = 1}^n \operatorname{trace}(E_{ij}^T \tau(E_{ij}))
$$
where $E_{ij}$ denotes the matrix with a $1$ in the $i,j$ entry and zeros elsewhere.

To compute the determinant, it is helpful to consider this map as a composition.  Namely, $\tau_A = \tau^{(1)}_A \circ \tau^{(2)}_A$, where
$$
\tau^{(1)}(X) = AX, \qquad \tau^{(2)}(X) = XA^T
$$
If you find the matrices of $\tau^{(1)}$ and $\tau^{(2)}$ relative to the basis $\{E_{ij}: 1 \leq i,j \leq n\}$ (taken in lexicographical order), then you will find that it is easy to compute $\det \tau^{(1)}$ and $\det \tau^{(2)}$ by exploiting the block-structure of these matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much, using your approach 2 suggestion I managed to solve it :).